# How do i open a link in a new tab when page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, tabs, onload

How do I have a new tab open a desired link when a user is loading the first page?. Similar to: [www.domain.com](http://domain.com).

Comment: Show us your efforts..

Comment: Call `window.open()`

Comment: this is what i have done so far `window.open(dimamp.com, '_blank');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function to the `onload` event of your `<body>` like :

`<body onLoad="newpage();">`

And then declare your function like this :

```
function newpage() {
    window.open("ad.com", '_blank');
}
```

Or you can even do it inline `<body onload="window.open('ad.com', '_blank');">`